# VBA download form URL with login that redirect to another one

Tags: vba, winhttprequest

the website requires login then redirect you to other url then download the file

this function works fine with url with no redirction but not with my case

```
Function DownloadFile(URL As String, Path As String, UserName As String, Password As String) As Boolean

    DownloadFile = False

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", URL, False, UserName, Password
    WinHttpReq.send

    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile Path, 2
    oStream.Close
    DownloadFile = True

End Function
```

when I try this code the status is 401 even that I use the username and password?

```
Function CheckStatus(ByVal strUrl As String, ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String) As String


    Const WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6
    Dim oHttp As Object

    Set oHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")


    oHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
    oHttp.Open "GET", strUrl, False, UserName, Password
    oHttp.send
    CheckStatus = oHttp.Status


End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you detect a 301 redirect with Microsoft.XMLHTTP object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594234/can-you-detect-a-301-redirect-with-microsoft-xmlhttp-object)

Comment: More related code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647297/xmlhttp-send-request-brings-back-nothing

Comment: Bottom line, use `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest` instead and enable the follow-redirects option. Either that or keep working with the `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` object and look at the response status (301 or 302) and the response headers (`Location`), i.e. follow redirects manually.

Comment: @Tomalak it is 302.

Comment: ...and? That's how HTTP authentication works. Every single request must have username and password.

Comment: @Tomalak so what should i do?

Comment: I don't follow. Which part of *"Every single request must have username and password."* is unclear?

Comment: @ that part is clear. but can you find out why the code is not working even the code you provide me it seems that it cant login the status is 401

Comment: I don't see the point of the `CheckHyperlink` function? Also I don't see you using `UserName` and `Password` in there, so it's not a surprise that you get a "401 Unautthorized" response. Again. **Every single request must have username and password.** (Also, this seems to be copy-and-paste code, instead of code you wrote yourself.)

Comment: hahaha my bad. it is copy and paste from the link you gave me but I change it and I use the username and password still the same status 401? any advice

Comment: The link I gave you was for you to figure out what to do, not to copy and paste the code and cross fingers. Setting username and password [works differently in WinHttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/authentication-using-script).

Comment: @Tomalak yes of course I changed the code to try it with my case, I dont have problem in authentication when using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 but it did not redirect. with WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 there is problem with authentication. I will see the link and get back to you. thank you

Answer (score 2):

WinHttp will follow the redirect by default. here is how to deal with username and password using WinHttp.

```
Function DownloadFile(ByVal URL As String, ByVal path As String, ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean

    DownloadFile = False

    Const HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER = 0
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Dim oStream As Object

    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", URL, False
    WinHttpReq.SetCredentials UserName, Password, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER
    WinHttpReq.send

    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile path, 2
    oStream.Close

    DownloadFile = True


End Function
```

Comment: Kudos for keeping at it, figuring it out and posting your working result. (Although I don't see anything related to redirects in there... is this no longer needed?)

Comment: @Tomalak yes there is no need for extra code, WinHttp will follow the redirect by default

Comment: Ahhh. Nice, I thought this would need to be enabled.