# Web Scraping requires JavaScript in XMLHTTP VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

Navigating to this link https://www.moi.gov.kw/main/eservices/residence/fines-enquiry and in the search box type the number `268101704418` and click on the Enquire button .. The result that appears is the required to get
This is what I have tried till now

```
Sub Get_Residency_Status_By_Civil_ID()
    Dim v, xx, ws As Worksheet, http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument, htmlData As New HTMLDocument, htmlAhkam As New HTMLDocument, oLinks As Object, postCasePane As Object, strArg As String, sAhkam As String, x As Integer, r As Long, lResult As Long, liflag As Long, lregno As Long, lccode As Long, lctype As Long, llvl As Long, lparentV As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index")
    For r = 2 To 2 'ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If r Mod 10 = 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Save
        If ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = "" Then GoTo Skipper
        
        With http
            .Open "GET", "https://www.moi.gov.kw/mfservices/immigration-fines/residency/" & ws.Range("A" & r).Value, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Stop
        End With
Skipper:
        Set html = Nothing: Set htmlData = Nothing: Set htmlAhkam = Nothing
    Next r
    MsgBox "Done...", 64
End Sub
```

The response text contains a message like that

```
<html><title>You are being redirected...</title>
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
<script>var s={},u,c,U,r,i,l=0,a,e=eval,w=String.fromCharCode,sucuri_cloudproxy_js='',S='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';L=S.length;U=0;r='';var A='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';for(u=0;u<64;u++){s[A.charAt(u)]=u;}for(i=0;i<L;i++){c=s[S.charAt(i)];U=(U<<6)+c;l+=6;while(l>=8){((a=(U>>>(l-=8))&0xff)||(i<(L-2)))&&(r+=w(a));}}e(r);</script></html>
```

Is there a solution or workaround for such sites that require JavaScript?

This is my attempt using python but I can't adjust the IF statement of `SUCESSFUL EXECUTION`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
s = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.moi.gov.kw/mfservices/immigration-fines/residency/'

def getdata(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, 'html.parser')
    #print(str(soup).split('":"')[1].split('"}')[0])
    if 'SUCESSFUL EXECUTION' in soup:
        return 'This Person Is Not Eligible'
    else:
        return str(soup).split('":"')[1].split('"}')[0]

result=[]
for item in ['236033100148', '295010900353']:
    nurl=url+str(item)
    result.append(getdata(nurl))

print(result)
```

Comment: Use Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can use selenium and is better than IE but I am trying to find a way using XMLHTTP as this is a faster approach ..

Comment: Use WinHttp which follows re-directs. If that solves then can mark as duplicate of something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59607726/6241235)

Comment: @QHarr Will use the original url or the url I have extracted from Network tab? I tried using winhttp but the same result.

Comment: I assume the one from network tab. However, it could be that there is some additional browser validation step that occurs.

Comment: Did you have a look at the website? Can you please have a look at the python code in the main post ..?

Comment: Use Internet Explorer the system component to browse the internet. WinHTTP, XMLHTTP, and ServerXMLHTTP, are each designed for getting specific data in different scenarios. None of them is for browsing.

Comment: You can automate IE as a component in your app or as a separate app. WINHTTP appears quick as it is not rendering the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot but using this library in python `requests_html` does the trick.